# Numbers in a Haystack simplification

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python course in Coursera that involves using regular expressions.  The purpose is the read through a file of text and numbers, extract all the numbers, and sum them.  For the sample data (http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_42.txt), I have the following code:

```
import re
handle = open("regex_sum_42.txt")
numlist=list()
for line in handle :
    line = line.rstrip()
    stuff = re.findall('([0-9.]+)',line)
    for element in stuff :
        try :
            num = int(element)
            numlist.append(num)
        except :
            continue
print(sum(numlist))
```

Since the "stuff" list also includes empty spaces (lines where there are no numbers) and '.', I thought I needed the try/except lines to prevent a traceback error.  Is there a simpler way to implement this program, without the second for loop?

Comment: Why do you add `.` if you want to parse integers?

Comment: Are you also trying to sum floating point numbers?

Comment: Your  regex is incorrect. Your pattern will match one or more digits zero through nine _**or**_ one or more decimal characters.  What you problably want is something more like this: `\d+(.\d+)?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you put a dot `.` into your regex since both your code and the sample data suggest that (a) you want to parse only integers, and (b) the sample file only contains integers.

If you only want to **parse integers**, you can simply use:

```
import re

rgx = re.compile(r'\-?\d+')

the_sum = 0
with open("regex_sum_42.txt") as handle:
    for line in handle:
        the_sum += sum(int(x) for x in rgx.findall(line))

print(the_sum)
```

So we use a regex that only matches numbers, and do not store these numbers into a list since it only costs memory. We can calculate the sum of that line immediately, and just sum these up. The regex contains also an optional sign `\-?` since negative numbers like `-2` are numbers as well. This then produces:

```
445833
```

In case **floats are allowed**. The problem is harder, since now it depends on what formats you allow. If you simply allow a decimal dot followed by zero or more digits, we can use:

```
import re

rgx = re.compile(r'\-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?')

the_sum = 0
with open("regex_sum_42.txt") as handle:
    for line in handle:
        the_sum += sum(float(x) for x in rgx.findall(line))

print(the_sum)
```

Note that we use a *non-capture group* `(?:..)` as regex, since otherwise `findall` will only return the capture part (the content after the decimal dot, dot included). The program then produces:

```
445833.0
```

## Word boundaries

The text contains a snippets like `'http://www.py4e.com/code3/'`, and this will parse `'4'` and `'3'` as numbers as well. We can use word boundaries `'\b'` to prevent that:

```
import re

rgx = re.compile(r'\b\-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?\b')

the_sum = 0
with open("regex_sum_42.txt") as handle:
    for line in handle:
        the_sum += sum(float(x) for x in rgx.findall(line))

print(the_sum)
```

Now it produces:

```
445822.0
```

So the result differs with the previous with a total of 11.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

fh=open("regex_sum_345631.txt")

rd=fh.read()

sums=0

x=re.findall("[0-9]+",rd)

for i in x:
    sums+=int(i)

print(sums)
```